# HTML5 JQuery - Encrypt game score before post?

Tags: jquery, html, encryption

I have a basic Space Invaders game in HTML5 that runs on a php page. Once the game ends I'm using JQuery to post the score to a page (that adds to database).

```
if (player.lives === 0) {
    $.post("submitscore.php", { 'score': player.score }, function(data){
        });
    }
```

I need a method to add an encryption so the user can't just post made up scores. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: Or can I check the source of the POST using php. If the score is being submitted from a different domain/page then ignore?

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40015/how-do-i-protect-sending-scores-from-html5-games-to-my-server

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem that you are wanting to solve, but the way you intend to solve it, unfortunately, won't work.

Anyone can deliver fake scores to your server simply by copying your JavaScript logic and executing it for a custom value of their chosing.

The only way to ensure you are receiving legitimate scores is to have the actual game logic itself on the server.

Additionally, even if encryption could solve this problem (it can't), you wouldn't want to implement it yourself.  HTTPS is more than enough.

Comment: What about making the POST check domain to verify where the source is coming from? Would that help instead?

Comment: Nope.  You can literally just press F12 to view developer console and manually send the request from reading your source.  This isn't something that you can "work around".  It simply just doesn't work this way.